# Appending a string into a value from an array

Tags: arrays, bash

Is there a way to append an Array element in bash? For Example:

```
$ declare -a MY_ARR=('Bob' 'Jim Jim' 'Dug Dug' 'Mark Mark')
$ echo "${MY_ARR[0]}"
Bob
$ MY_ARR[0]<< "bob"
$ echo "${MY_ARR[0]}"
Bob bob
```

I'm pretty sure that there is a relatively simple way of doing this in PHP but I can't seem to find a bash solution.

**Just to clarify I want to add something to the current array element not overwrite it.**

EDIT: I want to append a current Array ***ELEMENT*** not add another element to the array. It is the actual array **ELEMENT** contents that I want to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare -a MY_ARR=('Bob' 'Jim Jim' 'Dug Dug' 'Mark Mark')
MY_ARR[0]+=" bob"
echo "${MY_ARR[0]}"
```

Output:

```
Bob bob
```

Comment: Please see update to clarify I do not want to append the array it is the array element

Comment: This adds something to the first array element. Take a look at: `declare -p MY_ARR`

Comment: @RixsonL `MY_ARR+=( " bob" )` would append to the **array**, Cyrus appended to the **element 0**.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying David. Yes that is correct Cyrus thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ declare -a MY_ARR=('Bob' 'Jim Jim' 'Dug Dug' 'Mark Mark')
$ echo "${MY_ARR[0]}"
bob
$ MY_ARR[0]="${MY_ARR[0]} bob"
$ echo "${MY_ARR[0]}"
bob bob
```

Comment: Glad to help. Lot of smart bash folks here `:)`

Comment: It's quite scary sometimes :)